# AS3 Traces Bitmap as "[object Shape]" / Bug or feature, going loco

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i need to use the GetPixel32 on an Object in a movieclip.

in order to get to that object i use:

```
var bitmap=clip.getChildAt(0);
//and then 
bitmap.bitmapData.getPixel32(x, y);
```

however, even though the childobject is a png i get an error and using

```
trace(clip.getChildAt(0));
```

traces "[object Shape]"

so does Flash convert certain bitmaps into shapes?

please see the this fla ( http://www.sendspace.com/file/uycmm5 ) to test it yourself.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like `clip.getChildAt(0)` is simply *not* a `Bitmap`. If it says `Shape` it's a `Shape`, what can I say? Show the code where you're adding your children to `clip` or so.

Comment: To add to Torious, 
    var bitmap:Bitmap= clip.getChildAt(0) as Bitmap;
    if bitmap is null here then it's definitely not a bitmap.

Comment: @Torious: please check the fla. the object IS a bitmap. the children ( aka the png image ) are not added via code, just lie in a frame.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bitmaps placed in Flash's timeline are converted to shapes (with bitmapfill) on compilation,
(**UPDATE**)
unless the image in the library has a linkage name, in which case it works as expected and compiles to a Bitmap object.

You can however draw a new bitmap with that shape:

```
var shape:DisplayObject = clip.getChildAt(0);
var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(shape.width, shape.height, true, 0);
bmp.draw(shape);
bmp.getPixel32(x, y);
```

Comment: But that does not seem to be the case always ?
In another clip with a different png the Bitmap gets correctly identified as [object Bitmap] ... !
The Bitmap.draw is not feasible in my case ( too performance hungry ).

Comment: @cay do you have some references to back up your initial statement?

Comment: No, actually I have no reference to back this up... it's only my experience: I've never found that an image placed in Flash IDE's timeline compiles to a bitmap object. @blofeld could you double check that? and maybe post some steps to reproduce it? (or post the fla)

Comment: @Cay I did post the fla, please check my original question.^

Comment: @Cay:    
Ah, sorry guess you mean the version where its working...  
here you go: http://www.sendspace.com/file/lar373

Comment: Oh nice! that's because that image has a linkage name, didn't know that... So if you just set a linkage name to your other image it should work fine :)

Comment: That is totally screwy. How can it be less expensive to display a Shape with a bitmap fill than the bitmap itself? Not to mention how insidious it is to change the type of an object out from under you and NOT EVEN DOCUMENT IT. How the hell did anyone ever figure this out before SO?